# User Defined Literal naming in C++

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer

In a recent code review I came across the following:

```cpp
constexpr Dimensionless operator"" _(...) {}
```

In my reading of the standard I cannot work out if this is UB, unspecified behaviour, or underspecified behaviour.

From [17.6.4.3.2 [global.names]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/global.names) we know that:

> Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the
> implementation for use as a name in the global namespace.

and from [17.6.4.3.5 [usrlit.suffix]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/usrlit.suffix) we know that UDLs are exempted:

> Literal suffix identifiers that do not start with an underscore are
> reserved for future standardization.

My question is:

Does the standard allow for a literal that is *only* an underscore (`42_`)?

Comment: 17.6.4.3.2 [global.names] is defective, it was fixed to say «Each identifier» instead of «Each name». The key thing here is that identifiers in your quote of the second bullet are reserved only **for use as a [name](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/basic#4)**: «A _name_ is a use of an identifier … that denotes an entity …». _identifier_ in _literal-operator-id_ is not a «use as a name». Also, declaring `operator"" _xxxx` doesn't prevent an implementation to use `_xxxx` identifier as a name (and this name won't denote `operator"" _xxxx`).

Comment: If I understand what you said correctly, then `operator"" _(...)` is actually perfectly valid and allowed, but the specification for C++14 did not accurately convey that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the standard allow for a literal that is only an underscore (`42_`)?

Yes.

---

As per [[lex.ext]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/lex.ext) the grammar of a *user-defined-literal*, for all families of user-defined literals, is:

```
<family-specific grammar> ud-suffix

ud-suffix:
    identifier
```

[[over.literal]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.literal#1) describes the limitations on the *ud-suffix* in the context of *user-defined-string-literal*:s:

> [...] The *ud-suffix* of the *user-defined-string-literal* or the identifier in a *literal-operator-id* is called a *literal suffix identifier*. Some *literal suffix identifiers* are reserved for future standardization; see [usrlit.suffix].

with [[usrlit.suffix]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/usrlit.suffix#1) highlighting that the *ud-suffix* must **start with** and underscore:

> Literal suffix identifiers that do not start with an underscore are reserved for future standardization.

This does not, however, reject an *ud-suffix* that is only an underscore.

[[lex.ext]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/lex.ext#3), [/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/lex.ext#4) and [/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/lex.ext#6) contains the sole wording on non-string user-defined literals, and none rejects an *ud-suffix* that is only an underscore.